# remotes install_github R packages fail with non-zero

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

**Question**

Try to install package 'fpp3' in RStudio from gitbub source of author.

**Environment**

RStudio 2021.09.2
R 4.1.2 via homebrew/Cellar

**GCC compiler**

So when my GCC (gfortran) is already installed, via brew, I still have this failure on package install

brew install gcc
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
Warning: gcc 11.2.0_3 is already installed and up-to-date.

** GCC Environment**

R_HOME: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R
CC: clang
CXX: clang++ -std=gnu++14
CFLAGS: -Wno-implicit-function-declaration
CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -
CXXFLAGS: -g -O2
LDFLAGS: -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib
LDFLAGS: -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -configure: CXX11 is: clang++, CXX11STD is: -std=gnu++11
CXX is: clang++ -std=gnu++11
C++11 support available
rgdal: 1.5-28
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 1158
checking for gdal-config... no

**Problem**

installation of dependencies package ‘urca’ had non-zero exit status, which resulted in non-zero exit for install.packages("fpp3")

Attempt to install (remotes:install_github("fpp3") **package 'fpp3' from github source, and received non-zero status on package 'urca'

**Error message**

```
remotes::install_github("robjhyndman/fpp3-package")
Downloading GitHub repo robjhyndman/fpp3-package@HEAD
Installing 1 packages: urca
Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/urca_1.3-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 682935 bytes (666 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 666 KB

* installing *source* package ‘urca’ ...
** package ‘urca’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c UnitRootMacKinnon.f -o UnitRootMacKinnon.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [UnitRootMacKinnon.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘urca’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/urca’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/zl/zh18_1yx1b74nzd6kt936mlh0000gn/T/RtmpnjKRRb/downloaded_packages’
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/zl/zh18_1yx1b74nzd6kt936mlh0000gn/T/RtmpnjKRRb/remotes165782277a586/robjhyndman-fpp3package-90153ad/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘fpp3’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory ‘fpp3/docs’
─  building ‘fpp3_0.4.0.9000.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency ‘urca’ is not available for package ‘fpp3’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library/fpp3’
Warning messages:
1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘urca’ had non-zero exit status
2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/zl/zh18_1yx1b74nzd6kt936mlh0000gn/T//RtmpnjKRRb/file1657850afd3be/fpp3_0.4.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `gfortran: No such file or directory` is the clear error here. I don't know how, but refocus your research to "how to install fortran on macos" (with or without homebrew).

Comment: brew install gcc. gcc includes gfortran. thanks so much for this helpful tip

Comment: in running brew install gcc. gcc 11.2.0_3 is already installed and up-to-date.

Comment: Okay, if you installed it correctly, does `Sys.which("gfortran")` return a valid path (i.e., not `""`)? Sorry, I don't have a mac, but errors like that are undebatable (though the fix is os-specific).

Comment: looks like my gfortran path is non-existent

Comment: Yes, so ... did you restart R (and, if you're using it, RStudio) after installing gcc/gfortran? If not, try that. If so, then you have bigger issues, in which case you will want to research how to make gcc/gfortran available based on whichever installation mechanism you chose (and/or other options). Again, sorry, I'm not a mac (or homebrew) user, so I cannot inform on that ... but I do see a lot of people having similar path-related problems with homebrew, so my guess is that you'll find something

Comment: man -k fortran
gfortran-11(1), gfortran(1) - GNU Fortran compiler
which gfortran
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran

Comment: looks like gfortran is install and in library gfortan

Comment: Sorry if I'm repeating myself unnecessarily, but ... since you install gfortran, have you restarted RStudio and R? If `/opt/homebrew/bin` in `Sys.getenv("PATH")`? If not, then .. one more research avenue, *"how to add a directory to my system path?"*. I suggest system-wide (or at least in your user's `.bashrc` files) instead of "just R" because often R init files (e.g., `~/.Rprofile`) are not loaded in some package-building modes, so it needs to be external to just R.